# GIT don't push my files

Tags: linux, git

I have a problem with git, here my process

I create a file git on the dev serv
`git init --bare .git`

I clone this repository .git on my local pc.
`git clone ssh://root@ipservdev.com/var/www/siteweb/.git`

i add all my files
`cd /var/www/siteweb
 git add *
 git commit -m "First Commit"
 git push -u ssh://root@ipservdev.com/var/www/siteweb/.git master`

But, i back on my dev server, none file of my site are uploaded (ex : index.php, config.php or others) . Why ?

Buy, I have no error.
`Counting objects: 3, done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 234 bytes, done.
Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
To ssh://root@ipservdev/var/www/siteweb/.git
 * [new branch]      master -> master
Branch master set up to track remote branch master from ssh://root@ipservdev/var/www/siteweb/.git.`

Answer (score 2):

Your repository is a 'bare repository', it didn't have a working directory with your pulled files.

Edit: I answer here, just for make it more clear and complete.
As far as I know, you have here three options:

1. From the most old repo, do a git pull targeting the most new repo, or make a merge
2. Do the push to another branch, the `master` branch is 'special'
3. Use a bare repo (like you do initially) to push it your commits, but you can't see the files because it didn't have a working directory

Also I recommend you to read de [pro-git book](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2) it's really useful and you will see a lot of common use cases.

Hope i help you!

Comment: if I delete "--bare" I have this message : Counting objects: 3, done.

Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 232 bytes, done.

Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)

remote: error: refusing to update checked out branch: refs/heads/master
....
.....
To ssh://root@IPSERVEURDEV/var/www/final/.git

 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (branch is currently checked out)

error: failed to push some refs to 'ssh://IPSERVEURDEV/var/www/final/.git'

Comment: That remote error shows when you try to push some files to the repo? 

When you clone the repo, there's no need to specify the route again in the push, use origin insted `git push origin master`

Comment: I show this error when i try to push some files to the rep without "--bare".

Comment: @jaki4513 i answer you in the upper answer, just for make it more clear.